# Why is myeclipse own's tomcat faster than the local tomcat I configure?

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, myeclipse

When I work with myeclipse Java EE project, I find by chance that myeclipse own's tomcat 7 runs with smaller memory and faster speed than the local tomcat 7. When I run project with local tomcat, it costs about 300M memory. But now with myeclipse own's tomcat, it only costs 100M memory and makes me feel like faster. I'm very happy to work with myeclipse now. But I'm still interested with the reason behind this situation. Who can explain it? Many thanks.

Comment: May be you have more webapps deployed on your standalone(local) tomcat but while using myeclipse tomcat that might be the only webapp running on it? Did you check that?

Comment: I think it can be one reason. I'll make sure there is one webapp running on tomcat in the future. Once tomacat made my computer very slow. Many thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can check VM arguments configured for your server in myeclipse and compare it with your local tomcat startup scripts.

Usually these IDEs provide some default values for -Xmx -Xss -XX:MaxPermSize etc.

Comment: Oh, I ignored this thing before. I'll check the difference between them carefully. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers and suggestions should be helpful. I offer this only to say that the MyEclipse built-in Tomcat 7 is exactly the same as an externally installed Tomcat 7, possibly differing only in the patch level (MyEclipse 2016 uses Tomcat 7.0.56). It is provided for convenience.